My Visual Studio stuck on Launching Local Functions process
I am currently using Visual Studio 2022. I have Azure functions project.
 <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>

I am trying to run the project locally on my machine. It has been working great past many months. Never had problem. Suddenly since this morning, the project is stuck saying "Launching Local Functions process".
Below is what I did:

Deleted Release folder. (C:\Users{yourUserName}\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases)
deleted stuff from %temp% folder
upgraded the Visual Studio to latest version of 2022.
Repaired Visual Studio.
restarted my Windows machine twice.


Delete AzureFunctionsTools and azure-functions-core-tools from C:\Users\ {YourUser} \AppData\Local and reinstall

Did that. did not help. All other Azure functions are working. only one project is having this problem

Do you have another Windows machine you can use temporarily? If not, and you are in great need, get an Windows VPS and RDP into it.

@Vinny, Is the function is dotnet-isolated? Provide your local.settings.json.

I can confirm that D A's response solved my issue.

Please post your sol as an answer.
